# Update Domain Class and Flush Session?

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-mvc, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I was wondering if I have to set flush: true when I do an operation on the database inside my domain class. For example:

```
class TreeNode {    

    TreeNode removeFromChildren(TreeNode child) {
       TreeNodeChild.findByNodeAndChild(this, child).delete(flush: true)
       this
    }
    ...
}
```

or is the following the correct notation?

```
class TreeNode {    

    TreeNode removeFromChildren(TreeNode child) {
       TreeNodeChild.findByNodeAndChild(this, child).delete()
       this
    }
    ...
}
```

The question is: Should I flush the session?

Answer (score 2):

Taking the definition of flush from [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/delete.html):

> If set to true the persistent context will be flushed resulting in the
>   instance being deleted immediately.

And there's more in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288991/do-i-ever-need-to-explicitly-flush-gorm-save-calls-in-grails) on SO. The relevant part to your question is:

> Let Hibernate do it's job and only manually flush the session when you
>   have to, or at least only at the end of a batch of updates. You should
>   only really use if you're not seeing the data in the database when it
>   should be there. I know that's a bit wishy-washy, but the
>   circumstances when such action is necessary depend on the database
>   implementation and other factors.

That said, you can let the caller of this method decide if it needs to be flushed:

```
TreeNode removeFromChildren(TreeNode child, boolean flush = false) {
  TreeNodeChild.findByNodeAndChild(this, child).delete(flush: flush)
  this
}
```