# Grails unique validation exception with two consecutive saves

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Let's assume **name** and **id** are the only fields on my user table and I have an unique constraints set for both. So if I have a value with **id 2**, **name "robel"**, why is the below code giving me validation exception?

```
User old = UserFindByName("robel")
old.setName("changed")
old.save(failOnError: true)
User neew = new User(name:"robel")
neew.save(failOnError: true)
```

I tried setting breakpoints and checking if the value of **old** is changed before saving **neew**,and i am sure its changed but the last line is giving me an exception saying name:"robel" needs to be unique .Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [flush changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289426/2166188) before adding new one instance. Change:

```
old.save(failOnError: true)
```

to:

```
old.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
```