# Can StaleObjectException still occur if Optimistic locking is disabled on a specific domain?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm getting StaleObjectStateException on my update operation on a domain model that has Optimistic Locking disabled.

So it does not have the ***version*** column.

I'm under the impression that it would not check at all if the object is stale.

I disabled the optimistic locking by adding this to the domain model:

```
static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

Comment: Should you not attempt to fix underlying issue rather than disabling this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296682/grails-transactions-and-the-session/39297300#39297300 try following .With New transaction as shown on above question. You may want to get object again within .With New transaction and updating/saving the new object within the block

Comment: In this specific case, we intentionally do not want optimistic locking since we do not care for it on that specific domain model.